# Inkscape: Set default values for "resize page to content"

Tags: inkscape

I use Inkscape 0.92 and frequently use the "resize page to content" tool (see snapshot below) with the same values for the margins. Naturally, I would like to be able to simply set a default value for the margins. Is that somehow possible?

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

1. In your Inkscape program directory, find the templates folder, and open the file named *default.svg*
2. Go into *File > Document properties*
3. Change the margins in the resize page to content section.
4. Close the document properties
5. *File > Save*, and then quit Inkscape

Now when you open Inkscape again, the default template will have the margins you set previously.

Comment: Better add that file into the user configuration directory's 'templates' subdirectory. It's not recommendable to modify installation files.